# C# protected override void "Does not exist in current context"

Tags: c#, overriding, protected

I have a class in which I override `OnPaint` for the control `Button`, and it gives me an error that

> Graphics G does not exist in current context

yet I have Graphics G defined.

```
abstract class ThemeContainer154 : Control
{
   #region " Initialization "
   protected Graphics G;
   protected Bitmap B;

public ThemeContainer154()
{
   SetStyle((ControlStyles)139270, true);

   _ImageSize = Size.Empty;
   Font = new Font("Verdana", 8);

   MeasureBitmap = new Bitmap(1, 1);
   MeasureGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(MeasureBitmap);

   DrawRadialPath = new GraphicsPath();

   InvalidateCustimization();
}
```

And here is the "Theme":

```
class NSButton : Control
{
   protected override void OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
   {
      G = e.Graphics;
  G.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
      G.Clear(BackColor);
  G.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
   }
}
```

The errors I get are:

```
 The name 'G' does not exist in the current context
```

Comment: Just make `G` a local variable in OnPaint().

Answer (score 3):

The NSButton does not inherit the ThemeContainer154 .

Change

```
class NSButton : Control
```

to

```
class NSButton : ThemeContainer154
```